# Missing "ADODB" assembly with Mono?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, mono, porting

I'm trying to port some ASP.Net code to mono. I am testing it using xsp2. I compile it with Visual Studio also before running it with xsp2.

Whenever I go to a practically blank page in my application I get

```
Parser Error Message: Assembly ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A not found
```

I have searched and not found any info anywhere about this. I know the web application makes use of Webparts and the SqlPersonalization thing which is not supported in Mono, but I'm going to basically a blank page with a master page and getting this strange error.

And I have ran Moma and it only complained about web parts and SqlPersonalization, neither of which are on the page I'm trying to view(or referenced in any way).

What could be the problem here? Has someone hit a problem like this before? Also I'm using the latest version of Mono on Windows

Comment: using ADODB in 2010 ? you must be kidding :P

Comment: yea, if someone will just help me to close this, its way too localized for me to explain at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADODB is the primary interop assembly for the old Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (ADO, aka MDAC) COM-based database access layer. Looks like the ASP.NET code you're trying to port uses an older, non-.NET data access library for some reason. I suspect that library doesn't, and never will, exist on Mono.

One solution would be to port the code that uses ADO to ADO.NET, if that's possible.

Comment: But thats the thing. We have zero code using ADO. We use nothing but ADO.Net. Wait.. maybe when I'm at work tomorrow I'll try removing some references and assemblies to see if that fixes it cause we have Crystal Reports and FastReports which both should be managed only, but not sure..

Comment: It was Fast Reports that was using adodb.. and they say "100% Managed Code" on their product page..